# PostgreSQL Select where multiple OR statements

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I have the following PgSQL query, in which i'm looking where user_id equals any one of a set of id's i am looking for.

Question is, is there a way to simply the statement so that I dont have to keep putting user_id= ?

```
SELECT * 
FROM comments 
WHERE session_id=1 
AND (user_id=10 OR user_id=11 
     OR user_id=12 OR user_id=13 
     OR user_id=14 OR user_id=15 
     OR user_id=16)
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM comments 
WHERE session_id=1 
  AND user_id in (10,11,12,13,14,15,16);
```

alternatively for this specific case:

```
SELECT * 
FROM comments 
WHERE session_id=1 
  AND user_id between 10 and 16;
```